# KC_TAB release is not registered in macro

Tags: qmk, qmk-firmware

I try to overwrite the behavior of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, if <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> is hold down. In that case, I want it to act like a <kbd>Shift</kbd> key:

```
    switch (keycode) {
    case KC_TAB:
        // If left alt is pressed, treat tab as left shift
        if (get_mods() == MOD_BIT(KC_LALT)) {
            if (record->event.pressed) {
                register_code(KC_LSFT);
            } else {
                unregister_code(KC_LSFT);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This works when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it is registered as <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>, but when I release the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key again, it still shows <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> as pressed. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out fortunately. The issue was the check if <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> was pressed. I replaced `get_mods() == MOD_BIT(KC_LALT)` with `get_mods() & MOD_BIT(KC_LALT)` as the first comparison would return false if <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> were pressed, which was the case when I was releasing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key again.